# Worksheet_SelectionChange event in xla add-in

Tags: events, excel, add-in, xla, vba

Is to possible to trigger `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event in xla add-in. I put the code in Worksheet module of add-in. but it did not enter into this module. My target is to set the comment box in the center of active window. I got the code from [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlcomments03.html). Please help me.

Comment: You need to work with Application-level events if you want to capture an event in another workbook.  See here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: @ Tim : Very thanks. Please post it as an answer :) I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work with Application-level events if you want to capture an event in another workbook. See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx)