# VBA Add-In - Count selected cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an existing add-in which has other functions to apply to many excel files. I would like to perform this action where I select x numbers of cell and if it exceeds 100 counts then it will prompt the user a message. This action should work at any workbook that I am going to open (and import the add-in into the workbook). I have looked at some links about application events but I still do not understand how it should work for me. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

I have referenced the following codes from

## 1 - https://superuser.com/questions/920578/count-number-of-selected-cells

## 2 - http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/using-message-box.shtml

**Codes:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim totalCells As Long
totalCells = ActiveSheet.Selection.Cells.Count

If totalCells > 100 Then
    MsgBox (totalCells)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: how does a user delete an entire row or column without selecting it first?

Comment: user won't be deleting row or column. the message prompt is to pop up when user selected more than 100 cells. and i want this action to be available to all the workbook users open as long as they import the add-in.

Comment: you need to trap and process events at application level. read tis http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx

Comment: Hi @cyboashu, I have read the website before posting this question. I tried their example on excel but it did not work when I open a new Workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I copied Chip Pearson's example, and added this code to ThisWorkbook of my addin, seems to work OK.  See if it works for you.

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim totalCells As Long
  totalCells = Target.Cells.Count
  If totalCells > 100 Then MsgBox totalCells
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set App = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi DaveU, it still did not work. This code is situated under add-in, Module3 (I tried putting it under ThisWorkbook but it still did not work).

Comment: Worksheet SelectionChange is a worksheet event, so the code must be under the worksheet you're working with, eg, Sheet1 for example.

Comment: Is it possible place in under add-in so it will be available to all workbook/worksheet which users are working on?

Comment: The thing is that OP wants to use an Add-In on any worksheet, I think that class modules would need to be created in this case.

Comment: @Ryszard, you're probably right, I was trying to keep things simple - maybe not a good idea in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442842/worksheet-selectionchange-event-in-xla-add-in

Comment: [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/385282-workbook_sheetselectionchange-code-run-add.html)

Comment: I am aware of the application event and have seen those links but I still can't figure out why it didn't work (using the example given in the website).

Comment: I changed my answer, see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you @DaveU, it worked for me! I was not sure where should I put my sub code because initially it worked within the worksheet itself. Deeply appreciate it!!